# Minimize the functional: $\int_a^b {x^2(y')^2dx}$

Tags: functional-analysis, euler-lagrange-equation

I have to minimize the following functional:

$\int_a^b {x^2(y')^2dx}$.

I used the Euler-Lagrange equation which gives:

$-\frac{d}{dx}2x^2y'=2xy'+x^2y''=0$,

which I found out is called a Euler-Cauchy equation. Is this correct or did I do the partial derivative the wrong way?
Thank you.

Comment: I assume that $a,b$ are constants and you want to find a $y$ to minimize the functional. Right?

Comment: Yes, I have values of $a,b$ that I used to solve the resulting ODE.

Comment: Note that the functional is non-negative and you can achieve zero by choosing $y$ to be...

Comment: I do not understand if the result of the Euler-Lagrange procedure is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the functional
$$I=\int_a^b L(x,y,y')dx$$
the Euler-Lagrange equation is
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)=0$$
Note that your equation is a special case where $L$ is not a function of $y$. Therefore the equation reduces to
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}=c\;\;(\text{constant})$$
So let $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x,c)$ and solve this ODE to obtain:
$$y=\int_a^x g(u,c)du+c_1$$
In your case, $L=(x y')^2$ results in
$$2x^2 y'=c$$
hence $g(x,c)=\frac{c}{2x^2}$ and I think you won't have any problems with the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why didn't you take also the derivative with respect to $x$ as I did?

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri : because the derivative with respect to $x$ is zero. So why bother?

Comment: Therefore if I solve $y'=g(x,c)$ I obtain the function $y=c_2-\frac{c}{2x}$ which is the solution to the minimization problem?

Comment: @LorenzoFabbri : yes